# masking hostname to IP address lookup in Linux/Bash/Perl

Tags: linux, perl, bash, rhel5

Many of the servers in our environment have their loop-back line in **`/etc/hosts`** configured like so:

```
127.0.0.1        mydevserver.testdomain.com mydevserver localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Normally, this is not an issue.  However, we are now dealing with some external software from a vendor that calls gethostbyaddr and their installer is designed to fail if the result of **`hostname --ip-address`** is 127.0.0.1.  This of course causes it to fail on our systems because the servers hostname is in the loopback line of `/etc/hosts`.

My question is, if I wrap the installer in a bash or perl script, is there a way to "mask" or temporarily alter the results of **`hostname --ip-address`** without changing the /etc/hosts file?

(Clarification: They are calling the gethostbyaddr() function from within their compiled binary installer. The way to get a similar result from command line is `hostname --ip-address`)

Comment: Things like this is why it's not uncommon to use some other `127.*.*.*` address like `127.0.1.1` instead for the FQDN of the server. I know this is not what you asked, so I'm just adding this as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be to write your own `gethostbyaddr()` function, compile it into a library (say, `libmyfunc.so`), then [preload it in a wrapper script](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-glibc.html) so the vendor's installer uses it rather than the system `gethostbyaddr()` :

```
#!/bin/bash    
export LD_PRELOAD=libmyfunc.so
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/path/to/crappy_vendor_binary $@
```

Comment: An ugly way to do it, but it may be a necessity due to the ugliness of the vendor's software.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own implementation of `hostname` that does the expected thing, put it somewhere, unshift that directory before `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, but they are calling the gethostbyaddr() function from within their compiled binary installer. The way to get a similar result from command line is **`hostname --ip-address`**.

Answer (score 1):

If the really call the hostname command, then nothing is easier than that: just replace it with your own version.

Comment: Thanks, but they are calling the gethostbyaddr() function from within their compiled binary installer. The way to get a similar result from command line is **`hostname --ip-address`**.

Comment: @Eli, then you better update your /etc/hosts. I am pretty sure there is no rational reason for your practice, is there? Since this is an installer, a temporary clean /etc/hosts would do.

Answer (score 0):

well if it's a plain BASH script, add this before the call of "hostname": 
`function hostname(){ echo -n; }`